# Hyperlink- Gives Run-Time Error 5 “invalid procedure call or argument”

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Having an issue where I'm trying to select A in the excel sheet where that's where the selection is at within the folder to call all the files and using the hyperlink, but this is the error I get with the following code:

```
 Sub Y_ADD_HYPERLINK_AMBETTER()
    
     Range("A4").Select
     Selection.End(xlDown).Select
     z = ActiveCell.Row
     a = 2
     
      Do Until a = z + 1
      
       Range("A" & a).Select
       Selection.Hyperlinks.Delete
       c = Range("A" & a).Value
       ' COMBINE PATH NAME IN CELL P & a
       'Range("P" & a) = "..\MOLINA%20-%20AGENTS%20COMMISSIONS%202017\MOLINA%20AGENTS%20COMMISSIONS\"
       Range("P" & a) = "..\AMB%20-%20AGENTS%20COMMISSIONS%202020\"
       Range("P" & a).Select
       ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell.Formula & c & ".xlsx"
       Path = Range("P" & a).Value
       ' GO TO HYPERLINK CELL
       Range("A" & a).Select
       ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=Path, TextToDisplay:=c
```

Comment: Does the activecell have a formula? `range("P" & a)`  did you want to add "c" to the value of `range("P" & a)` ?

Comment: When you get an error you need to explain what line is in error.